# I am looking for a word to describe a person who takes joy in creating (food, art, etc.) and loves to learn about the world and its cultures

Tags: single-word-requests

I guess I am looking for a word that describes a person who is passionate about taking in all they can from the world - learning, creating, traveling, eating, photographing, etc. Please help if you can!

Comment: Emphasis on the passion and not on the learning? (Like *polymath* would.)

Comment: Renaissance man?

Comment: I think the French phrase, *joie de vivre" fits here:  meaning joy of living, used to mean enjoyment or love of life.

Comment: 'Cosmopolitan' might suit your needs

Comment: Possibly, a [bon vivant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_vivant).

Comment: Those are all great - I think bon vivant may be closest to what I am looking for if I can't find a single word to describe it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to come up with a single word to grasp it all, but here are a few words I thought might fit.

-aesthete: Someone who enjoys visual arts, music or simply beauty.

-hedonist: Someone who embraces and pursues pleasure.

-epicurean: Someone who loves to eat good food, drink good wine or generally, having fun.

Passionate or curious might be a bit too simple but not completely wrong.

Comment: epicurean and aesthete are definitely closer to what I am looking for - If only there was something that combined the two, haha. thank you! This really helps me!